# Data Studio Community Connector - How do I fetch data from a CSV file in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: looker-studio

I just wanted to to check if you can connect to a storage bucket address through the Community connector service. We have a CSV file which would be generated as part of the getConfig() function

GetConfig() triggers user input
Based on user input -> generate csv file and store in gs://....../newDataSource.csv
Pass storage Url back to Data Studio to query rather than passing Data object.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CSV is publicly accessible in your GCS bucket, you can use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to fetch the file in your `getData` function. Rather than using the `gs://....../newDataSource.csv` path, use the public https path for the CSV when you are making the `UrlFetchApp` call.